# One-One relationship constraint

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, data-modeling

i actually want to implement a compulsory one-one relationship between two tables from my ERD in Oracle. The two tables are Governor and State. A governor can govern only one state and a state must have one and only one governor. I want to implement that in Oracle. I have written the queries as follows

```
create table gov
(gid number(3) ,name varchar2(100),
constraint gov_pk primary key (gid)
);

create table state
(
sid number(3) ,
name varchar2(100),
gid number(3),
constraint state_pk primary key (sid),
constraint gov_state_fk foreign key (gid) references gov(gid),
constraint state_uk unique(gid,name)
);
```

But that does not seem to work. I could not find any alternative way. Please help me with this. I will be thankful to you. And please let me know why is is failing to establish one-one relationship.

Comment: You probably want a unique key on just gid in the state table

Comment: The model doesn't make much sense. You may have a "state" table and that may be fixed (in most cases, and at least for certain amounts of time). What else do you want to have - a table of Governors, with personal data such as birth date and name? What if a person is no longer Governor, do you delete them from the table? If not, then it's not a one-to-one relationship - on one side you may have "zero or one". If you really need to always keep it exactly one to one, why do you need two tables? Write all the Governor attributes in the State table.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy for your reply. It really helped remove a lot of my confusions. But still i want to ask why would it not be a one-one relation if i delete a governer from table?

Comment: If you remove a governor from a table when they are not re-elected, then the relationship is, indeed, one-to-one - but in that case it's not clear why you need two separate tables. More likely (more common), you would have a table "politicians" or "potential governors" where a person may be governor of a state OR not be a governor at all (the "state" column in this table, for this politician, may be NULL). And you do not remove "politicians" from the table when they are no longer governors. That makes sense, but the relationship is one-to-(zero or one). This is the common arrangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close to successfully implementing your requirements.

> " a state must have one and only one governer"

So make GID mandatory on STATE table.

> "A governer can govern only one state "

So enforce a unique key on just GID.

```
create table state
(
sid number(3) ,
name varchar2(100),
gid number(3) not null,
constraint state_pk primary key (sid),
constraint gov_state_fk foreign key (gid) references gov(gid),
constraint state_uk unique(gid)
);
```

---

> "I can successfully add data to gov table with out adding any row in state table."

Enforcing *a Parent must have a Child* relationship is pretty hard.

- SQL standards have the concept of Assertions, which could enforce that kind of business rule, but Oracle (nor any other DBMS vendor) have not implemented them.
- a foreign key on GOV referencing STATE is right out, because circular dependencies are deadly.
- that leaves us with a trigger on GOV.

Here is such a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger enforce_gov_state 
    before insert or update on gov
    for each row
is
    l_sid state.sid%type;
begin
    select s.sid into l_sid
    from state s
    where s.gid = :new.gid;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Governor must have a state');
end;
/
```

So that's okay then. Just one little wrinkle: *how do we insert rows into either table????* We can't insert into GOV until the state exists; we can't insert into STATE until the governor exists.

There is a workaround: defer the foreign key on STATE so it's not enforced until the whole transaction is committed. This permits the creation of STATE record followed by  GOV record. Of course, we need to know the value of STATE.GID before we create the GOV record.

Also, there are similar snags attached to changing the GOV - STATE relationship. Except that it can be solved by updating all the GOV attributes (except GID) to fit a new Governor. Which is kind of sketchy but there you go.

---

Why does Oracle make this so hard? Often a one-to-one relationship between tables which is mandatory on both sides points to a flawed data model.

1. Sometimes 1:1 points to a single table. That is unsatisfactory when
   we have two distinct entities such as here.
2. More likely the 1:1
   relationship is wrong, and it's actually 1:N or even M:N. Consider
   that a State can have many Governors, one current, many previous and
   optionally one elect. Likewise a politician can theoretically be
   Governor of more than one state over the course of a career.

So a more truthful implementation would have STATE_GOV as an intersection table between STATE and GOV. It is much simpler to maintain such a table, which is a good sign.

Comment: This also does not work. I can successfully add data to gov table with out adding any row in state table.

Answer (score 2):

Remove FK from state table. Having it and making it unique means you can't enter a state without already knowing the governor. Create an intersection table between State and Gov with a unique constraint on each FK:

```
create table StateGov(
  StateID   number( 3 ) not null references State( sid ),
  GovID     number( 3 ) not null references Gov( gid ),
  constraint UQ_StateGov_State unique StateID,
  constraint UQ_StateGov_Gov unique GovID
);
```

No state can appear more than once, no governor can appear more than once. No circular references, no assertions, no problem with inserting a state record before you know the governor.

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique constraint to STATE:

```
create table state
(
sid number(3) ,
name varchar2(100),
gid number(3),
constraint state_pk primary key (sid),
constraint gov_state_fk foreign key (gid) references gov(gid),
constraint state_uk unique(gid,name)
constraint gov_state_uk unique (gid)
);
```

Comment: *name='A' - git=1 and name='A' - git=2*. Not work =(. I guess he should create unique index on name field which will assure unique set of state records and as result one-one relationship with gov table

Comment: That does not seem to work. If i apply one-one constraint then data in any table should not be inserted without the required data in the other table. Suppose i want to insert a new governer then there must also be inserted a state related to him otherwise data should not be inserted but this is inerting only governers in the table and that should not be possible.

Comment: Hi,, SkyWalker can you explain that please?

Comment: @SalmanAli If every state needs a governer and every governer needs a state why not just have 1 table?